# philosophy statistics identity null hypothesis

Tags: statistics, philosophy, hypothesis-testing

Many companies are experimenting with “flex-time,” allowing employees to choose their schedules with broad limits set by management. Among other things, flex-time is supposed to reduce absenteeism.

One firm knows that in the past few years, employees have averaged 6.3 days off from work (apart from vacations). This year the firm introduces flex-time. Management chooses a simple random sample of 100 employees to follow in detail, and at the end of the year, these employees average 5.5 days off from work, and the standard deviation is 2.9 days.

What is the null hypothesis?

(A) The average days off work for the employees in the sample is different from the average days off work for the employees overall.

(B) The average days off work for the employees in the sample is the same as the average days off work for the employees overall.

I think it would be B but I am not sure. I do not really understand null hypothesis. Would it be the contrary of what he is trying to prove?

Comment: You are correct that B is the null hypothesis.  A null hypothesis is generally understood to be contrasted with an *experimental* hypothesis.  Broadly the experimental hypothesis would be that introducing flex-time changes (reduces) absenteeism (measured as days off from work apart from vacations).  So A is one possible experimental hypothesis, and B is the corresponding null hypothesis.  Perhaps you have an interest in the "philosophy" behind these concepts.  The Question reads as an assignment you are passing along to Readers, and adding your thoughts for choosing B would improve it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes a lot more sense now.